# How to add a XML node for Some case in pattern matching?

Tags: xml, scala

I want that the nodes test1, test2 and test3 appear only if `option` is defined.
The code below works, however, I don't like test1 because it does not use pattern matching (and so I need to call `option.get`); I don't like test2 because I have a useless line `case _ =>`. and I don't like test3 because I have the equivalent `.getOrElse(())`. Is there a nice way to achieve this?

```
val option: Option[Int] = None

val node =
  <test>
    { if (option.isDefined) <test1>{option.get}</test1> }

    { option match {
        case Some(x) => <test2>{x}</test2>
        case _ =>
    }}

    { option.map(x => <test3>{x}</test3>).getOrElse(()) }
  </test>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
val node = <test> { option.iterator.map(x => <test1>x</test1>) } </test>
```

If you turn the `Option` into an `Iterator` then I think you get the semantics you're looking for with the native XML handling (should also work with `toList` and others).

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're only concerned with `Some` case while ignoring `None`:

```
def f(o: Option[Int]): scala.xml.Elem =
  <test>
  {
    o match {
      case Some(x) => <test1>{x}</test1><test2>{x}</test2><test3>{x}</test3>
      case None => xml.NodeSeq.Empty
    }
  }
  </test>
```